# Create new SVGNumber or other SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to create SVGNumber object dynamically and append it to SVGFEColorMatrixElement:

```
var feColorMatrix = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feColorMatrix");
var numberList = this.feColorMatrix.values.baseVal;
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    // var number = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "SVGNumber"); // doesn't work either
    // number.value = 0;
    var number = {value:0};
    numberList.appendItem(number);
}
```

As SVGNumber is interface, by my understanding, this should work fine, but I get this error message:

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendItem' on 'SVGNumberList': parameter 1 is not of type 'SVGNumber'**

What would be a correct way to create such objects like SVGNumber, SVGAnimatedNumber or SVGNumberList?

SVGNumber interface: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGNumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a function on the `<svg>` element that can be used to create an SVGNumber object. It's called [createSVGNumber](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__createSVGNumber)

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");

var feColorMatrix = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feColorMatrix");
var numberList = this.feColorMatrix.values.baseVal;
for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  var number = svg.createSVGNumber();
  number.value = 0;
  numberList.appendItem(number);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you cannot directly instantiate `SVGNumber`. On top of that, according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimatedNumberList), the `baseVal` property is readonly.

A workaround is to set the `values` attributes on the `<feColorMatrix>` element, and the browser will instantiate `SVGNumber` for you. Here is an example:

```
var feColorMatrix = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feColorMatrix");

var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    values.push(i);
}

feColorMatrix.setAttribute("values", values);
console.log(feColorMatrix.values.baseVal);
// feColorMatrix.values.baseVal contains SVGNumber instances as expected
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is mostly wrong. You can create an SVGNumber via createSVGNumber on the svg element. baseVal is readonly in that you can't directly modify it via baseVal = x but it has functions that do allow you to modify it. The workaround is therefore unnecessary.